# How to center text over jQuery mobile widget

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I need to have two pieces of text over the slider in mobile application I am working on.

Here is a mockup what I need:

[image: slider labels on top]

I need the 'Not at all' flush with beginning of the slider track and the 'Very much' flush with the end of it. A user can rotate the phone so that the application goes to landscape mode and I need the labels to stay flush with the slider track regardless of the device's orientation.

What are the CSS rules to achieve this?

**Update**

Here is the code for my slider widgets:

```
    '<h3>Think about how you feel right now:</h3>\
    <h2>Right now, I feel:</h2>\
    <div class="jqmslidercontsurvey1a">\
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="jquerymobileslidercont">\
            <label for="slider-happy" class="sliderlabel">Happy:</label>\
            <input type="range" name="slider-happy" id="slider-happy" value="" min="1" max="10" step="1" class="jquerymobileslider" data-highlight="true" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true">\
        </div>\
        \
         <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="jquerymobileslidercont">\
            <label for="slider-relax" class="sliderlabel">Relaxed:</label>\
            <input type="range" name="slider-relax" id="slider-relax" value="" min="1" max="10" step="1" class="jquerymobileslider" data-highlight="true" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true">\
        </div>\
        \
         <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="jquerymobileslidercont">\
            <label for="slider-cheer" class="sliderlabel">Cheerful:</label>\
            <input type="range" name="slider-cheer" id="slider-cheer" value="" min="1" max="10" step="1" class="jquerymobileslider" data-highlight="true" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true">\
        </div>\
    </div>';
```

I am not sure what type of text element I should use, so I don't have any code that pertains to the text above the sliders... I was thinking a header with ids though

Comment: Could you please show some of your code, that you have done till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use a `fieldcontain` role around each label/slider pair, you can just add a `<div>` with 2 `<span>` tags between the `<label>` and `<input>`, then use some CSS to line them up.

```
<div  class="jquerymobileslidercont">
    <label for="slider-happy" class="sliderlabel">Happy:</label>
    <div><span class="leftSpan">Not at all</span><span  class="rightSpan">Very much</span></div>
    <input type="range" name="slider-happy" id="slider-happy" value="" min="1" max="10" step="1" class="jquerymobileslider" data-highlight="true" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true" />
</div>

.jquerymobileslidercont .leftSpan{
    margin-left: 68px;
}
.jquerymobileslidercont .rightSpan{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

The second `<span>` is positioned to the right via absolute positioning.  If you want different font, font-size, color, etc. for these labels, just add to these CSS rules.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Fha5x/)**